# MySql trigger not works

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, sql-update, declare

I have 3 tables

```
tbl_payments(pay_id,date,amount,description,-------)
tbl_pay_trans(pay_id,trans_id)
tbl_transactions(trans_id,trans_date,trans_amount,trans_description,-----)
```

'tbl_transaction' has the same data from the 'tbl_payments' along with some other values. To maintain the relationship between the two tables I use 'tbl_pay_trans'. What I want to do is, when an update done on tbl_payments(amount,description) the same changes need to do in tbl_transactions(trans_amount,trans_description). I wrote a trigger to do that, but it dose not update the tbl_transaction table values as it supposed to.

My trigger is

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_trans 
    AFTER UPDATE on tbl_payments
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_amount VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE new_description TEXT;
    DECLARE new_pay_id,new_trans_id INT;

    SET new_pay_id = OLD.pay_id;
    SET new_amount = OLD.amount;
    SET new_description = OLD.description;
    SELECT trans_id INTO new_trans_id FROM tbl_pay_trans WHERE pay_id = new_pay_id;

    UPDATE tbl_transactions SET 
    trans_amount = new_amount,
    trans_description = new_description
    WHERE trans_id = new_trans_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Please someone help me to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Your missing a length on your `VARCHAR` it should be e.g. `VARCHAR(50)`

Comment: Thnx @Nick, That was the error. I corrected it. but the trigger doesn't do what it supposed to do. It didn't update the values on tbl_transaction. Dosen't give an error now though. I updated my question for the new problem aroused.

Comment: I figured that the problem is in this line.
SELECT trans_id INTO new_trans_id FROM tbl_pay_trans WHERE pay_id = new_pay_id;

Comment: You do have a problem with your `new_amount` and `new_description` lines. Your `SELECT` looks fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not updating because you are using `OLD` on the `amount` and `description` columns where you need to use `NEW` i.e.

```
SET new_amount = NEW.amount;
SET new_description = NEW.description;
```

`OLD` refers to the column value **before** the update occurred in `tbl_payments`. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).